# How to setup TextMate to work with Haskel

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, text-editors, haskell

I am new to mac, and am in the process of getting my computer setup with all the programs I need, one of them being Haskell.

To my surprise, the Haskell platform for OS X is not like in Windows (where there is a GUI editor built on the platform installation - *winGHiC*). After looking a lot around, I found this editor *TextMate* which is supposed to be compatible with Haskell but am finding it quite complex to setup the [Haskell Bundle](https://github.com/textmate/haskell.tmbundle) for it.

I have already downloaded and installed the following:

- Haskell Platform for Mac OS X
- Xcode 3. 4 *(Haskell Prerequisite)*
- TextMate

  - Haskell. Tmbundle files *(mentioned above)*

Is anyone familiar on how to get it working? It will mean a lot to me a detailed stepwise explanation, like I said, I has been only 1 day since I used OS X for the first time.

Comment: Crossposted at [Setting up TextMate for Haskell programming on Mac OS X - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682339/setting-up-textmate-for-haskell-programming-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: You know, if you don't like an answer, you're supposed to mention that in a comment instead of giving up on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite easy -- Github just renames the actual folder to have a prefix, which is unfortunate.

Download the `tmbundle`, unzip it by double-clicking, then rename the `textmate-haskell.tmbundle-5d41f32` folder to `textmate-haskell.tmbundle`.

`tmbundle` is a TextMate bundle extension, so it will appear as a file afterwards. Double-click the file to add the bundle to TextMate.

---

Alternatively, get (or use — don't know if it's bundled out of the box) the *Get Bundles* bundle to add a bundle manager and downloader to TextMate

---

Alternatively, if you use `git`, check out the `haskell.tmbundle` from GitHub into `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/`

Comment: This came up on stackoverflow recently:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682339/setting-up-textmate-for-haskell-programming-on-mac-os-x